# create button with custom functionality

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to add a custom button to amcharts, just like the 'Show All' in the right corner with lens icon when zooming in, but, with different functionality.

i.e http://www.amcharts.com/demos/chart-with-gaps-in-data/

I could't find it in the API reference, I was wondering if such functionality exists?

What I have in mind is,

add a label with a class using

`allLabels: [{... 'id': 'custom-button'}];`

then replace that label with the similar SVG code as the 'Show all' button

`$('.custom-button').replaceWith(...);`

`<g transform="translate(962,48)" visibility="visible">
        <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="96" height="33" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="1" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" opacity="0" transform="translate(-8,-8)" class="amcharts-zoom-out-bg"></rect>
        <image x="0" y="0" width="19" height="19" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/lens.svg" class="amcharts-zoom-out-image"></image>
        <text y="7" fill="#000000" font-family="Lato" font-size="14px" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" class="amcharts-zoom-out-label" transform="translate(24,7)"><tspan y="7" x="0">Show all</tspan></text>
    </g>`

lastly, create handler for 'click' event with `$('..').on('click', function(){...})`

Is there more clean solution?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a button in HTML and just place it over amCharts area using CSS positioning?

Comment: Sort of like in this demo: http://www.amcharts.com/tips/custom-zoom-out-button/

Comment: You are right, I overcomplicated it.